# Cohen-Macaulay property of graded ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings, cohen-macaulay

Let $R=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $I$ be a graded ideal of $R$.
My question is the following: if $R/I$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring then $I$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ideal?

Comment: No. What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, in which sense "tried"? Is there something that we can add to the ideal to get the claim? Something like "R/I is Cohen-Macaulay + I is (?), then I is Cohen-Macaulay"

Comment: A common abuse of language in commutative algebra is that when people talk about an ideal having a property, what they mean is the quotient ring having that property

Comment: Yes, it's either true by definition if one means the ideal $I$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ideal, or it's false if one means $I$ to be Cohen-Macaulay as an $R$-module, but it's not clear what is intended by the question.

Comment: Yes, I mean if I is Cohen-Macaulay as ideal of R. Why should it be true in this case? I understand that R/I is CM if and only if I is CM as ideal. For that reason can we abuse with the language?

Comment: This is the definition: a Cohen-Macaulay ideal is an ideal for which $R/I$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring.

Comment: Ah ok. I never saw that in the usual books like definition. Do you have a reference? For me a Cohen-Macaulay ideal is an ideal whose heigth is equal to its depth.

Comment: In that case, you are using non-standard terminology and should be precise about your definitions and what exactly it is you are asking. Every ideal in a Cohen-Macaulay ring has grade equal to its height, but not every ideal in a Cohen-Macaulay ring is Cohen-Macaulay. For instance, if $S=k[x,y]$ and $I=(x^2,xy)$ then $\operatorname{ht}(I)=\operatorname{grade}(I)=1$, but $I$ is famously not Cohen-Macaulay. On the other hand, if $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$ and $I=(x,y)$, then $R/I \cong k$ is Cohen-Macaulay but $\operatorname{grade}(I)=0$ while $\operatorname{ht}(I)=1$.

Comment: My question arises in particular in the understand the following which comes from the linkage theory: let $I \subset K[x_1,\dots,x_n$ be a graded Cohen–Macaulay ideal, $J \subset I$ be a complete intersection with
$\mathrm{height} I = \mathrm{height} J$, and let $R = S/I$. Then the canonical module of $R$ is isomorphic to $(J : I)/J.$

Comment: Ah, sorry then! So I'm little bit confused with the notations. I'm reading a paper on some graded ideals where in many propositions the authors write "Suppose that $I$
 is Cohen-Macaulay"  or "Suppose that $I$
 is a Cohen-Macaulay ideal" so I suppose now that it means that the quotient ring $K[x1,…,xn]/I$, that is a Cohen-Macaulay ring, that is $\mathrm{dim}(R)=\mathrm{depth}(R).$

Comment: @Hola Yes, this is what the notion of a Cohen-Macaulay ideal means in this context. It is common to refer to a ideal having a typical ring theoretic property to mean $R/I$ has this property. E.g., $I$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ideal if $R/I$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring, $I$ is a Gorenstein ideal if $R/I$ is a Gorenstein ring etc. For the linkage result, Cohen-Macaulayness is a necessary condition for existence of a canonical module, so we have no hope without it.

Comment: Ok, great! Thank you very much for helping!